# Unable to operate my Tablet

Tags: windows-10

I have a "Connect" Wndows10 Tablet. It has been working fine but now when I turn it on I get a blue screen with  the message DRIVER OVERRAN STACK BUFFER. 
It then gives the message preparing automatic repair. I then end up with a page giving me the option of Continue, Use a device, reset your PC or turn off your PC. My problem is that none of these options will respond. I do not have a recovery disc only the option to reset /mirror image when I am able to operate the tablet.  Is there anything I can I do to make it usable or must I bin it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). A part of asking a good question is doing some research before you ask, and letting us know what you already tried. Please update your question so that it shows that you put in some effort before posting your question here.

Comment: I have searched the internet but I cannot find anyone who knows the answer so I do hope you can help me.